# Synchronize module at command line

Tags: ansible, synchronize

Ansible `'localhost' -m synchronize -a 'src: /home/qemu/images dest: /media/SamsungLinuxDr'`

Why doesnt the above work? Should `synchronize` always be run in playbook?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `=` rather than `:`.  For example:

```
ansible localhost -m synchronize -a "src=/tmp/foo dest=/tmp/bar"
```

In the future, it might help both googlers and answerers if you post the error you got as well.

Comment: @user2388292 If you accept the answer, the universe will gift you with karma and good fortune :)